# transfer local database (SQILLIT) on the Web(internet) in xamarin cod C# for Android

Tags: sql, sqlite, xamarin, transfer

I want to transfer my local database on the Web, Please help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.IO;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using Java.IO;

namespace Forooshgah
{
    class cls_Connection
    {
    private static  string DatabaseName = "DB_Forooshgah.db3";
    private static  string path =      System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);


    private static  string DatabaseNameEndofYear;
    private static  Java.IO.File _dirBackup = new Java.IO.File(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),  "Do2ta/backup");



    public static string getConnectionString()
    {
        string db = Path.Combine (path, DatabaseName);
        return db;
    }


    public static SqliteConnection setConnection()
    {
        var databasePath = Path.Combine(path, DatabaseName);
        //return new SqliteConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};Password={1}", databasePath, "test"));
        return new SqliteConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};",  databasePath));
    }
```

Comment: So what´s your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This code is "Upload File using FTP"

```
    protected void Upload(string dbpath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            string url = "ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx";
            FtpWebRequest request =(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.UseBinary = true;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","someone@somesite.com");


            FileStream file  = File.OpenRead(dbpath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Length];
            file.Read (buffer, 0, (int)file.Length);
            file.Close ();

            Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
            ftpStream.Write (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ftpStream.Close ();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();


        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks to Your response. But
Now i use local database (single sqlite3) in my application , I want change it and use multi user database on the internet . how can i do it?
help me please
( Android c # code for Xamarin)